# In a powershell pipeline how to remove trailing LF character?

Tags: powershell

Windows 2012 R2, Hyper-V 2012 R2, SCVMM, PowerShell...

...I'm generating a list of VMs using:

```
Get-SCVirtualMachine -All `
| Select-Object Name, ComputerName, Status, Memory, CPUCount, Location, VMHost `
| Sort-Object   Name, ComputerName `
| Select        Name, ComputerName, Status, @{e={[math]::Round($_.Memory/1024)}}, CPUCount, Location, VMHost `
| Export-CSV -Path "get-vms.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

...but for one of the VMs, the ComputerName text (when it prints "getaddrinfo failed") contains a trailing LF (char 0x10) and I can't work out how to strip it off.

The problem entry in the exported CSV file looks like:

```
B:\> type get-vms.csv
...
"client02","client02.blah.com","Running","12","4","C:\Storage\CSV02\client02","host02.blah.com"
"client03","getaddrinfo failed
","Running","2","1","C:\Storage\CSV03\client03","host03.blah.com"
...
```

And to show the evidence of a trailing LineFeed character, I copied get-vms.csv to a.a and to b.b, and then used notepad to edit b.b and delete the hidden invisible character, and saved, and then did a binary file compare, which shows:

```
B:\>fc /b a.a b.b
Comparing files a.a and B.B
00012DE7: 0A 22
00012DE8: 22 2C
00012DEA: 2C 22
...
```

I've tried to use this expression in the "| Select" clause, i.e. just before the Export-CSV:

```
@{e={[string]::Replace($_.ComputerName,[char]0x0A,"l")}}
```

...in place of just:

```
ComputerName
```

...but then the script fails to properly report the ComputerName of all VMs, i.e. when I use my attempt to strip off the bad character, my CSV file then looks like:

```
B:\> type get-vms.csv
...
"client02",,"Running","12","4","C:\Storage\CSV02\client02","host02.blah.com"
"client03",,"Running","2","1","C:\Storage\CSV03\client03","host03.blah.com"
...
```

...i.e. notice how the ComputerName item at the second field is now effectively reporting nothing/null.

Needless to say, I'm scratching my head... how do I strip the unwanted LF character yet still display the ComputerName text ?

Comment: `[string]::Replace($_.ComputerName,[char]0x0A,"l")` -> `$_.ComputerName.Replace([char]0x0A,"l")`

Comment: That seems like a bug with `Get-SCVirtualMachine`.  It shouldn't ouput an error message to stdout like that.  You may want to report it on Microsoft Connect, or whatever bug reporting system the SCVMM team uses.

Comment: Hi PetSerAl - thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately it generates an error:  You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Comment: Hi BaconBits - I think you are right.  If I send the same inputs and selections to output via Format-Table, then I don't get the nasty trailing LF char on that one ComputerName text field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain Powershell for this too, instead of .NET specific code.
The newline characters is represented by ``n` in PS. So you can simply replace it with an empty string to remove it like this:

```
ComputerName -replace "`n",""
```

If you put that in your select it should be something like this:

```
Select Name, @{ Name = "ComputerName"; Expression = {$_.ComputerName -replace "`n","" }}, ...
```

A workaround would be to use a for loop (% { ...}) in the pipe and create a custom PS object containing the properties you need, filtering the LF out of the name and using that to export. That might be faster, but I'm not sure.
Something like this:

```
<get,sort objects etc> 
| % { [PSCustomObject] @{ "ComputerName" = $_.ComputerName -replace "`n","" ; "Status" = $_.Status } } 
| <export to csv>
```

Comment: Jack, thanks for the reply, but I still get an empty/null ComputerName field in the CSV file, plus this seems to really slow down PowerShell an awful lot.  Using just ComputerName in the "Select" clause then the script takes about 8 seconds to list 500 VMs, but with this "-replace" the script takes over 150 seconds.

Comment: If you drop the CSV export and just let it output in a console, do you get nulls there as well? If so there is still something wrong with the select statement. Btw, I think you only need 1 select in there and not 2. Try figuring out what's wrong with the select statement first. Once that works you can add the sorting and the csv export again.

Comment: Thanks Jack.  If I take out the second Select, the same thing happens.  If I keep the second Select but output via Format-Table then I don't see the LF, but then the column gets truncated, and so the problem field lists as "getaddrinfo fail...", and so this truncation may be hiding/chopping the trailing LF.  I'll see if I can widen the output for this column in Format-Table.

Comment: You have to keep the select which contains the statement to remove the LF character from the ComputerName field. I don't know why that transformation is so slow though. If I try this on file names for example I don't really notice any difference.

Comment: I added another possible solution to the answer. Maybe try that and see if it works or is faster than the other one.

Comment: | Format-Table `
@{ Expression = {                $_.Name         } ; Label = "ShortName" ; Width = 20 } `
,@{ Expression = {                $_.ComputerName } ; Label = "LongName"  ; Width = 39 } `
,@{ Expression = {                $_.Status       } ; Label = "Status"    ; Width = 12 ; Align = "Left" } `
,@{ Expression = { [math]::round( $_.Memory )     } ; Label = "RAM"       ; Width =  4 } `
,@{ Expression = {                $_.CPUCount     } ; Label = "CPU"       ; Width =  4 } `
,@{ Expression = {                $_.Location     } ; Label = "Location"  ; Width = 55 }

Comment: Thanks for the persistence Jack.  I did try wider output via FT, and it was ok.  I'll try to get some time this weekend to follow your other more recent points.  Thank you.  D.

Comment: Cool. It would be great if you could mark my answer as correct as well, as it did fix the initial LF issue. 

Comment: Sorry jack, I'm lost, I'm a noob to PS.  I see two of { but three of }.

Comment: Hmm, that isn't correct indeed. Fixed it. There shouldn't be a brace inside the hash table @{ ... } and the properties of the hash table have to be separated by a semi-colon and not a comma. If you want to learn more about hash tables, check out this ebook btw : http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebookv2/archive/2012/03/11/chapter-4-arrays-and-hashtables.aspx